# Herencia en C++

Tags: c++, herencia

He estado tratando de aprender herencia en C++, pero he tenido algunos problemas con los constructores. Abajo pongo un código de prueba que hice.

Clase1.h

```
#ifndef CLASE1_H_INCLUDED
#define CLASE1_H_INCLUDED

using namespace std;

class clase1
{
private:
    int val1;
public:
    clase1(int);
    
};

#endif
```

Clase1.cpp

```
#include "clase1.h"

clase1::clase1(int valDado1)
{
    val1 = valDado1;
}
```

Clase2.h

```
#ifndef CLASE2_H_INCLUDED
#define CLASE2_H_INCLUDED

#include "clase1.h"
using namespace std;

class clase2: public clase1
{
private:
    int val2;
public:
    clase2(int);
};

#endif
```

Clase2.cpp

```
#include "clase2.h"

clase2::clase2(int valDado2):clase1(valDado1)
{
    val2 = valDado2;
}
```

Al tratar de compilar, manda el siguiente error:

```
clase2.cpp: In constructor 'clase2::clase2(int)':
clase2.cpp:3:37: error: 'valDado1' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'valDado2'?
    3 | clase2::clase2(int valDado2):clase1(valDado1)
      |                                     ^~~~~~~~
      |                                     valDado2
```

¿Alguien podría decirme qué hice mal?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: En tu definición del constructor de `clase2` el argumento que recibe se llama `valDado2`, `valDado1` es el nombre del argumento dentro del constructor de `clase1`. Debes pasarle una variable que exista en el ámbito (scope) de `clase2`.

Answer (score 0):

No existe ninguna variable ni parámetro llamado `valDado1` en el contexto del constructor de la `clase2`. Pero sí `valDado2`.

Si quieres llamar al constructor de la `clase1` para que `val1` de la `clase1` también tenga el valor de `valDado2`, el código debería ser el siguiente:

```
clase2::clase2(int valDado2) : clase1(valDado2)
{
    val2 = valDado2;
}
```